# I'm concerned this code isn't doing what I want it to because of the way objects are used

Tags: c++, multithreading, shared-memory

I have the following code and I was wondering if someone could look at it for me.

I have a multi-threaded application that all share an object and operate on it. I've created a pointer to a certain element of it, just so I don't have to type in the long path every time, but I'm concerned it might simply be modifying a copy of the shared object, rather than the shared object itself.

Here is the code:

```
RPCThread* thr = &(args->s->_shared-_>rpcThread[args->threadIndex]);
...
thr->_in_use = true;
...
sema_post(&(thr->_sem_result));
```

Is this valid or would this just be modifying a copy?

Comment: TLI! You need to tell us more about your data structures... But I don't see anything that would make a copy here, so until I get more information a tentative response would be you are modifying the right object... but not necessarily thread safely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on the type of member _rpcThread.  If it's simply RPCThread[] or *RPCThread
then I don't think you have a problem.  If it's a class type then you need
to know the return type of its operator[].  If the relevant definition is
returning a value rather than a reference, you probably have a copy.

Unless, of course, RPCThread is a class that uses the envelope-letter idiom or implements a virtual Proxy.

If _rpcThread is just an array, you shouldn't have an aliasing issue here of the kind about which you're asking.

Here's a good thing to check without doing much more code reading.  Can you change this:

```
 RPCThread* thr = &(args->s->_shared->_rpcThread[args->threadIndex]);
```

to this:

```
 RPCThread* thr = args->s->_shared->_rpcThread + args->threadIndex;
```

without causing a compile-time error?

Comment: that bodes well... it's always possible there are some weird conversion operator overloads, but I guess the other thing to check is that different threads think they have the same address (log the address from different threads as a hex value, check for identity)